# Optimisation for cropping

Tags: final-cut-pro, automation

I use final cut pro and I have to do a large amount of cropping and ken burns transition.

The picture cropped is always a corner forth of the video. So far to do it I use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then I have to manually select if I want to use crop or ken burns and use mouse to select the size for the new frame. I helps for cropping when you resize it to a forth it magnetizes to exact forth, when you do the same with ken burns it does not and this makes video to appear 'jumpy' if not done with enough precision.

Is there anything I can do to automate this process, perhaps a way to set shortcuts to change the selection size to preset size or similar?

Thank you